# OpenCV does not find VideoCapture for webcam or show on Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, capture

**Webcam capture does not show when the data is read**

I tried `video_capture= cv2.VideoCapture()` method for both, 0 and 700 as argument, because of suggestions and this happened:

- 0 gives out the error; CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame.
- 700 gives out a blank screen only first row of pixels are filled;
- `video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(700)` works only when I debug and breakpoint at cv2.imshow("Capturing", gray). Screen shows a snapshot of a webcam video, however runtime shows the following image;
- [Video screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EerSc.png)
- I have tried on my mac with the same python file, it worked perfectly fine. There is something wrong with Windows 10 that I can't figure out.

=======

```
import cv2

# Create an object. 700 for my external camera
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(700)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    #Check if the video is being read
    if ret == False:
        print("Connection Failed!")
    else:

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(gray, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', gray)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('e'):
            break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: May I suggest you trying `video = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`.

Comment: I have tried -1 as well, however it does not connect.

Comment: Check `video.isOpened()` whether it is True or False.

Comment: video.isOpened() results True and while I debug I can see the frozen image of video_capture.

Comment: At which line of the code does your program stops running?

Comment: Program works non-stop however Video screen shows blank black screen as I shared above.

Comment: Is there any parallel OpenCV code running? Does `cv2.putText()` method works fine and shows any thing on the black window?

Comment: When i debug the text, box, grey everything seems to be ok; https://imgur.com/0tX8tK7
However, runtime does not show live captures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kaspersky seemed to block my live webcam capture on terminal running code so on pycharm I have enabled, Run with Python Console. Everything is working fine now.
[Pycharm Console Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBFda.png)

Answer (score -1):

This problem can arise if you are using any Antivirus which has local device control or centralized device control. Please check your antivirus software and disable device control.